# Non Java VM based PHP/JS IDE for MAC OSX?

Tags: php

I'm a PHP developer and I use Eclipse on Mac (through Java VM), however - it seems to be very slow responsive when working with large source files (sometimes it is inevitable to edit such files).

That forces me to open subject file in some editor like TextMate or TextWrangler because these two handle large files much better than Eclipse.

I assume this is because Eclipse is driven on a Java VM, and probably TextMate and TextWrangler aren't (not sure though)?

Therefore, I'm wondering if someone could recommend some good IDE for PHP/JS for MAC OSX not based on Java VM (TextMate and/or TextWrangler are too narrowed to be used as IDE)? It is not important for such IDE to be freeware, as long as it is not too expensive.

Thanks in advance,
     Radovan

Comment: Look through the responses to the dozens of other "PHP IDE" questions for non-JVM answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166/any-good-php-ide-preferably-free-or-cheap

Comment: Yes but that thread is rather "what editor you like" than "non-Java based IDE".

Answer (score 2):

Don't underestimate the power of TextMate.  The Emacs style macros can do a lot very quickly. Still, aside from the intuitive shortcuts and macro's the program is rather "dumb".

Coda by Panic is a good step in the right direction. I usually alternate between the two depending on what I'm working on.

There's actually a lot of support for PHP related tasks in Dreamweaver but... it's Dreamweaver so, it has the same "fatty" problems that most Java based apps do.

There's a program call Espresso, I believe by macrabbit, that's rather similar to Coda, but in the brief time I gave it, preferred Coda.

XCode can handle PHP projects, but it's clearly not the right tool for the job. The file merge program that it comes with is very useful though.

OS X is really missing a clean, intuitive, cocoa based PHP/JS/CSS editor that includes things like code sense, macros, code folding, project management, version control integration.  Coda's the best start IMHO, but still not a home run.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about non-JVM PHP IDEs, but loading big files is not an "intrinsic" problem of Java VM (the VM can handle big files as the same way as a native application, so the problem is not there.. how the IDE renders the editor could be another cause).

If you couldn't find a good non-Java VM alternative, there are some things that you could do to improve the performance with large files by change the JVM startup parameters used by Eclipse (you can do something similar for other Java based IDEs).

- Show the package contents of your Eclipse.app and edit Contents/MacOS/eclipse.ini
- At the end of that file you have JVM startup arguments you can look into the [JVM documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html)
- A parameter that will affect the performance with large files is -Xmx which indicates the maximum memory available for the Java application, if the value is low or not present (the default is low for the IDE needs) your IDE will be slow because it spends a lot of time doing garbage collection (in Eclipse you can check if this is the problem by activating Eclipse->Preferences...->General / Show heap status -or something like that)

Here is an example of the startup parameters that I use for Eclipse (I'm using a MacBook with 4Gb of RAM):

```
-XX:PermSize=32m
-XX:MaxPermSize=384m
-Xms20m
-Xmx1024m
-Xss2m
-Xverify:none
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled
```

-Xverify:none turns off JVM bycode verification and makes Eclipse to load a little bit faster.

-Xms20m (is the initial heap size) is low.. the JVM will allocate more as needed, a big value maybe is better for other kinds of apps but in this case it makes Eclipse slower to load

-Xmx1024m use 1gb as maximum heap (I work with big Java projects and the heap never reached more than 600m)

Comment: Java Virtual Machines have a memory limit so loading big files is an "intrinsic" problem for java based IDEs. Many java based IDEs will give you a warning when you try to open too big of a file that it will fill up the VM's memory and cause performance to come to a halt.

Comment: The memory limit is that you mention is the heap size limit, and all the GC based VMs have that kind of limit so they can control how the heap grows and when the different GC algorithms are trigged.

Comment: But you can setup that limit to any size as long you have memory available. Then there is also how the IDE handles the file, if it loads an AST in-memory to give you refactorings/syntax highlight depends on each IDE implementation. You can hit the same limits regardless of the programming language where the IDE is implemented. The JVM doesn't impose any intrinsic limit. For an example of a JVM app: Apache Solr handles big index files in memory (by big I mean in the order of GBs, which is bigger than any source code)

Comment: Any Virtual Machine will have worse performance than a language that is run natively. It's intrinsic.

Answer (score 0):

I found my Mac Air battery was getting annihilated with Netbeans normally 8-10 hours usage down to about 1-2 with background scanning disabled, not good if your travelling!!

TextMate. Extremely lightweight,unnoticeable on consumption but has all the normal syntax features and GIT integration. When I'm not on my desktop this is the answer.